# depth of Breadth First Search

Tags: java, web-crawler, breadth-first-search

I am new to Algos and DS. I need to implement a webcrawler using BFS. I have come so far...but since I am using a queue, I am not able to get the depth.

```
public void BFS() {
    String link = "";
    while (mainSet.size() <= 100 && depth < 5) {
        if (queue.size() >=1) {
            System.out.println(queue);
            link = queue.removeFirst();
            System.out.println("Link shifted from queue!");
            System.out.println(link);
            String html = fetchContent(link);
            fetchLinks(html);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Completed!!");
            break;
        }
    }
}

public String fetchContent(String strLink) {
    String html = "";
    URLConnection connection = null;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        connection = new URL(strLink).openConnection();
        scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            html = scanner.next();
            visited.add(strLink);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    } finally {
        if (scanner!= null)
            scanner.close();
    }
    return html;
}

public void fetchLinks(String html) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

    for (Element link: links)  {
        String group = link.attr("href");
        if ((!group.contains(".css")) && (!group.contains(".ico")) && (!group.contains(".jpg")) && (!group.contains(" "))
                && (!group.contains(".gif")) && (!group.contains(".pdf")) && (!group.contains(".zip")) && (!group.contains(".asc")) 
                && (!group.contains(".rar")) && (!group.contains(".png")) && (!group.contains(".7z")) 
                && (!group.contains(".djvu")) && (!group.contains(".chm")) && (!group.contains(".mp3")) 
                && (!group.contains(".ogg")) && (!group.contains(".rm")) && (!group.contains(".wav")) 
                && (!group.contains("mailto:")) && (!group.contains("#")) && (!group.contains(".xml")) 
                && (!group.contains(".js")) && (!group.contains("news:")) && (!group.contains("mail:")) 
                && (!group.contains(".txt")) && (!group.contains(".bz2")) && (!group.contains(".gz"))
                && (!group.contains("javascript:")) && (!group.contains("exe")) && (!group.contains("vbs"))) {
            group = group.replaceAll("'", "");
            group = group.replaceAll("\"", "");

            if ((group.indexOf("http") == -1)) {
                if (group.charAt(0) != '/') {
                    group = parent + group;
                } else if(group.charAt(0) == '/') {
                    group = scheme + "://" + authority + group;
                }
                System.out.println("RelLink: " + group);
                mainSet.add(group);
            } else if (group.startsWith(parent)) {
                System.out.println("SeedLink: " + group);
                mainSet.add(group);
            }
            if (!visited.contains(group)) {
                if (group.startsWith(parent)) {
                    queue.add(group);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to limit the crawler by depth. Also I would like to know how to remove duplicates from the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit depth, you could create a class that encapsulates the depth and the page to fetch. You can even put some your functions into that class:

```
public class Page {
  private final int depth;
  private final String url;

  public Page(String url, int depth) {
    this.url = url;
    this.depth = depth;
  }

  private Set<String> fetchLinks(html) {
    // use your implementation, but return the links instead
    // of adding them to a queue. Using a set removes duplicates
  }

  /**
    * Fetches the URL represented by this page, and
    * add pages to the queue for all pages linked to
    * by the page.
    */
  public void visitPage(Queue<Page> workQueue) {
     String html = fetchContent(url);

     if (depth == 5) {
       // in too deep!
       return;
     }

     for (String link : fetchLinks(html)) {
       workQueue.add(new Page(link, depth + 1));
     }
   } 
}
```

As for removing duplicates, you could either use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `Queue` (to prevent duplicates in the queue) or maintain a `Set` of fetched pages (to prevent fetching a page multiple times).